# SQL Patindex / Regex - Match where there are 4 or less characters between 2 apostrophes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, patindex

I have the following string:

```
'Siemens','Simatic','Microbox','PC','27','6ES7677AA200PA0','6ES7','677AA200PA0'
```

I want to remove any "terms" that are less than 5 characters.  So in this case I'd like to remove 'PC', '27' and '6ES7'.

Which would result in:

```
'Siemens','Simatic','Microbox','6ES7677AA200PA0','677AA200PA0'
```

This is in SQL server and I have a function that accepts a regex command, so far it looks like this:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_StripCharacters(title, '/^''PC''$/')
```

I tried to hardcode to remove 'PC' but I think its removing all apostrophes, and 'P' and 'C' characters:

```
Siemens,Simati,Mirobox,,427B,6ES76477AA200A0,6ES7,6477AA200A0
```

This is the function I'm using:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_StripCharacters]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @MatchExpression VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @MatchExpression =  '%['+@MatchExpression+']%'
    
    WHILE PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String) > 0
        SET @String = Stuff(@String, PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String), 1, '')
    
    RETURN @String
    
END
```

Comment: Does the actual string have single quotes in it?

Comment: Yeah! I think thats half the problem tbh

Comment: You should really move away from storing CSV like this.  Instead, store each CSV value on a separate row.  Then, your requirement becomes very easy.

Comment: I don't have a choice unfortunately, the data comes from a 3rd party.  I could replace the apostrophes with another symbol, would that make the regex easier? I'm naff with regex

Comment: _the data comes from a 3rd party_ That does not prevent you for "correcting" it during import and storing it in proper normalized tables. That is a traditional and common function of ETL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *don't* care about the particular order of the words which are retained after filtering off words 4 characters or less, you could use `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, value
    FROM yourTable
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(val, ',')
)

SELECT id, STRING_AGG(value, ',') AS val
FROM cte
WHERE LEN(value) > 6
GROUP BY id;
```

### Demo

Comment: Sorry gotta say that this is amazing.  I have no idea how you guys come up with this stuff.  It works perfectly for my needs and also gives freedom for messing with the WHERE clause.  Thanks again

Comment: @Lee After answering several thousand SQL Server questions, plus having used it for more than a decade, you pick up tricks here and there.  By the way, to get to know a real SQL guru on this site, [check out Gordon Linoff's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff).